# Combine UseRetry() and UseScheduledRedelivery() using MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Is it possible to combine these two methods on the consumer side in a way that if an exception occurs during message consuming, the first thing that happens would be to retry, and when retry policy is exhausted, then the message will be redelivered via quartz using InMemoryScheduler? The behavior I got when combining these methods is that for each redelivery I would get a retry, but that's not what I need...I would like to know if it is possible to get retry first, and only then get redelivery but without additional retry attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in the documentation that explains exactly how to do what you want [here](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html#redelivering-messages)

In short, you need to configure the message scheduler, and then add the filter in the order shown below for it work as you expect:

```
cfg.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/quartz"));

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "submit-order", e =>
{
    e.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
    e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));
    e.Consumer(() => new SubmitOrderConsumer(sessionFactory));
});
```

This example will provide initial immediate retries (you can use any retry policy with either filter) and use redeliveries after the immediate retries are exhausted.

Comment: Not really, they are separate. The `UseMessageRetry` should really be limited to transient faults, whereas redelivery is more often used to handle long outages or business condition exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in documentation, but did the configuration a little bit different, so that was a problem. Now it's working as expected. I have one more question. Does message redelivery, blocks a thread in a same way as retry does?

Comment: Message redelivery does not block the thread, or hold a concurrent message slot/prefetch count slot, the message is later redelivered to the queue and picked up.